# How can I implement this Truth Table with MUX4 only?

Tags: design, circuit-design

I have implemented twice this function with MUX4, but I always fail at some point. I need some help, please

[image: table]

Thank you so much

edit: This is what I've done:

[image: MUX]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52039/discussion-on-question-by-jose-how-can-i-implement-this-truth-table-with-mux4-on).

Answer (score 2):

As you will see below, José was extremely close. Never give up!

[image: MultiPlexer Map]

```
Assuming X1:X0 (IN2:IN1) is the right hand multiplexer in José's diagram.

For RH mux input D0 selected:

X3  X2  X1  X0    Z(D0)
 0   0   0   0    1
 0   1   0   0    1
 1   0   0   0    1 
 1   1   0   0    x - choose x=1

Z=1 for all 4 entries!
We simply set RH mux D0 to 1, above four entries work.
José got RH D0 exactly right.
Four entries done, 12 to go!

Next up: RH Mux input D3 selected:

X3  X2  X1  X0    Z(D3)
 0   0   1   1    0
 0   1   1   1    0
 1   0   1   1    x - choose x=0
 1   1   1   1    x - choose x=0

Z=0 for all 4 entries!
We simply set RH Mux D3 to 0, above four entries also work.
José also did these 4 entries correctly.

8 Entries Done, 8 to go!
```

That was the easy half.  Now for a slightly harder challenge:

```
Show the last two remaining RH Mux input sets.
In the LEFT  column, X1:X0 selects input D2.
In the RIGHT column, X1:X0 selects input D1.

X3  X2  X1  X0  Z(D2) Z(D1) X3  X2  X1  X0
 0   0   1   0    0     0   0   0   0   1
 0   1   1   0    1     1   0   1   0   1
 1   0   1   0    x     1   1   0   0   1
 1   1   1   0    x     x   1   1   0   1

 If we choose x wisely we get the two sets to have identical outputs:

 0   0   1   0    0     0   0   0   0   1
 0   1   1   0    1     1   0   1   0   1
 1   0   1   0    1     1   1   0   0   1
 1   1   1   0    0     0   1   1   0   1
```

This means we can use **exactly the same function** for D1 & D2 inputs on the RH mux.

José **correctly created this function** using the left hand mux.

He also **correctly connected** the RH mux input D1 to the function.

All 16 table entries done, we are done!

José, you were extremely close, good work :)